# Do R Markdown Parameterized Reports require an R Studio Connect server?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

Before I invest too much time in it I need to know... *Do R Markdown Parameterized Reports require an R Studio Connect server?*

If they do that's a little outside of my budget and what I want to get into.

I'd like to be able to send out static `.html` files people can upload their `data.csv` into, and another `.html` file will be spit out based off my scripts and R Markdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Parametrized Rmarkdown reports](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/developer_parameterized_reports) are a feature provided by the `rmarkdown` package (>= version 0.8). They do not require a RStudio Connect Server. However, you will still need a running R process *somewhere* to render the report based on the provided parameters.